# Django OneToOneField unicode method

Tags: python, django, unicode

I'm building a Django application to model soccer games. Two of my models are:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    arsenal = models.OneToOneField('Roster', related_name="arsenalRoster")
    opponent = models.OneToOneField('Roster', related_name="opponentRoster")
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ...

class Roster(models.Model):
    squad = models.ForeignKey('Squad')

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.squad.season.footballClub.name is "Arsenal Football Club":
            return u'%s, @%s' % (self.match.date, self.match.location)
        else:
            return u'%s, %s' % (self.match.date, self.squad.season.footballClub.name)
```

Now obviously I cannot return self.match.date because there is no instance attribute to access the match object, and appropriately I am getting an error: `AttributeError: 'Roster' object has no attribute 'match'`. However this is the information I'd like to return depending on the given conditions. Is it possible to access the instance data from the Match object from the Roster object? How can I achieve what I am trying to do here without changing the models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use related_name instead of `match`:

```
#self.match.date
self.arsenalRoster.date
```

or (you have 2 link to `Roster` in `Match` model):

```
self.opponentRoster.date
```

Comment: Using the related name gives me a DoesNotExist error: `raise self.related.model.DoesNotExist DoesNotExist`

Comment: @ChrisClouten you should check if related object exist